# Display Popup to IP Range

Tags: popup, ip, range

In order prevent and legal conflict, I need to display a window (with specific message) to specific country ip range.

I have searched a lot but haven't found any working solution.

But i am not expert and i believe only expert can help.

I am using this script http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/stickynote.htm

http://community.plus.net/forum/index.php/topic,62744.0.html/

and i want to display message to more than 500 range in below format...

1.9.0.0/16

1.10.0.0/21

Answer (score 0):

I found the perfect solution. Thinking this will help others, i am sharing it.....

http://www.phptutorial.info/iptocountry/identification_of_specific_countries.html